# Maven not pulling artifacts from Nexus registry

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, nexus

I have maven artifacts stored in a private nexus registry. I'm expecting these to be pulled down when running a `mvn clean install`. However, it is attempting to pull from maven's public repo instead:

```
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.7.RELEASE.pom
```

I've configured the user settings.xml in `~/.m2/` to use the nexus registry:

```
<server>
    <id>maven-group</id>
    <username>***</username>
    <password>***</password>
</server>

<server>
    <id>nexus.host</id>
    <username>***</username>
    <password>***</password>
</server>
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

I've tried to define the settings.xml file with the command `mvn -s ~/.m2/settings.xml clean install`, but this does not resolve it.

It appears to be reading the correct settings.xml file:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from ~/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from ~/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from ~/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from ~/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at ~/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for ~/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

Comment: Your settings.xml snippet does not show any mirrorOf configuration... that is needed.  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Maven+Repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven

Comment: Yes I was missing the mirror. Thank you